# Angular/Ionic app - CORS issue despite everything server side is set up properly

Tags: angular, http, ionic3, http-headers, cors

I'm developing an Ionic 3 / Angular app which we've started to deploy onto iOS devices. At this point we're now running into CORS issues when we make requests to our server for data. As it's a 'not simple' request, the app does a pre-flight request to check the actual POST request will be valid, and this is where it fails.

[image: Image of request being made from Chrome Dev Tools]

However, I can see that I have set up the correct response headers at server side:

[image: Image of successful request being made with Postman]

The screenshot is from Postman which works, but I know Postman isn't the best measure here of indication.

I just don't see what I'm doing wrong here: I'm matching the Origin, the allowed Methods.

The only thing that isn't clear, is when you do the request and view it through Chrome Dev Tools, it does not include the Authorization header in the *Request Headers* section. I am definitely applying this in my code, but it doesn't appear here when the request fails.

Any guidance here could give me would be appreciated.

Thank you,
bengrah

Comment: You need your server to return http status code of 200 on `OPTIONS` request, wether user is authenticated or not. For now, your server is expecting an `Authorization` header, which won't be sent by your browser.

Comment: Hi David, but the browser is what controls whether an OPTIONS request gets sent or not. If I do this on our Android version of the app, no OPTIONS request is ever sent, just a POST according to Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: Yes, you can't change that. Browsers might implement CORS differently. That's why you need to modify the server

Comment: So to change the server behaviour so if I receive an OPTIONS request send back a 200?

Comment: Yes, that should solve the issue

Comment: Hi David - so forcing a 200 response code now, and I can see this in Postman - but still getting 401/Preflight issue when I deploy app to the device. One thing I started looking at is we're using the cordova-plugin-whitelist in order to whitelist network requests.

I've added this:`<access origin="https://endpointurl.com/*" />`

Into my `config.xml` but still getting the same issue

Comment: Is it the same  error?  Can you confirm that you are not sending the `Authorization` header when you do a `OPTIONS` request in Postman?  Can you also post the headers and response for `OPTIONS` request for both Postman and angular, for both request and response.